# How to concatenate certain strings in PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation

I'm creating a PowerShell script to create a unique ID based off of some AD info. Here is what I have so far.

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
$username = Read-Host -Prompt ("Please Enter the Username")
$startdate = Read-Host -Prompt ("Please Enter the user's Start Date (Format: Feb 2022 = 022022)")
```

Basically I want to create another variable called $UserID that will concatenate the first letter of the given name for the Active Directory user + first letter of the surname for the Active Directory user but lowercase + $startdate. So for example, if I input jdoe for username for John Doe in AD and the startdate is 022022, UserID should be Jd022022.

Is there a way to concatenate this in PowerShell?

Comment: is the input for `$username` used to query AD to get the user's `GivenName` and `Surname` to then get their initials ? It's not quite clear

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes exactly, the input is to search AD via username to get the user's GiverName and Surname.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks for your response :P it encouraged me to increase my verbosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.tolower()` and `.Substring()` methods to do this.

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
$username = Read-Host -Prompt ('Please Enter the Username')
$startdate = Read-Host -Prompt ("Please Enter the user's Start Date (Format: Feb 2022 = 022022)")
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $username
$finalvariable = $user.GivenName.Substring(0,1) + $user.Surname.Substring(0,1).tolower() + $startdate
$finalvariable
```

You could use this as a reusuable function with arguments like below.

### Nicknamer

```
function Generate-NewID {
  <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Nicknamer

    .DESCRIPTION
    Provides nickname given username and date.

    .PARAMETER user
    
    The samAccountName of the User.

       The specified date.

    .PARAMETER date
    
      The specified date.

    .EXAMPLE

      Generate-NewID -user mjones -date 010122
    
        > Mj010122

    .NOTES
    Place additional notes here.


    .OUTPUTS
    Nickname in the correct format.
  

#>



  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
      ValueFromPipeline = $true,
      HelpMessage = 'Please Enter the Username')]
    [Object]$user, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
      ValueFromPipeline = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Please Enter the user's Start Date (Format: Feb 2022 = 022022)")]
    [Object]$date
  )
  Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

  try {

    ## test if AD user exists
    $null = Get-ADUser -Identity $user
  }
  catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
    ##can't find that user
    Write-Warning -Message 'There was an error finding that user.'
  }
  catch {
    ## a different issue 
    ## if you are seeing this you need to remove the
    ## "$null =" in the above try{} block
    Write-Warning -Message 'Other issues...'
  }
  finally {

    $inputuser = Get-ADUser -Identity $user
    $startdate = $date
    $output = $inputuser.GivenName.Substring(0, 1) + $inputuser.Surname.Substring(0, 1).tolower() + $startdate
    $inputuser = $null
    $user = $null
  }
  $output 
}
```